# How do you fix correct hard drive not found error on PS3?

Tags: ps3

I upgraded the hard drive of my 60 GB Playstation 3 to a 300 GB one.  Everything works great, except for occasionally when you start the PS3 up it will freeze at an error screen saying that the correct hard drive was not found.  Sometimes restarting will fix this error, but it seems to only come up at random.

How do I get this error message to stop coming up ever again?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd check is the hard drive is properly seated. It sounds like your suffering from an intermittent connection.

Comment: Very interesting.  I will check this out when I get home from work.

Comment: I wish this would have fixed it, but unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do a backup of any save information.
2. Make sure pins are in good condition on both the hard drive and PS3
   connector (check dust levels as well)
3. Plug it into a PC and do a zero data wipe using any compatible
   utility.
4. Plug it back into your PS3 and let your PS3 format it.

Verify that the hard drive specifications are equivalent, ie RPM, disk I/O, cache size.